# Different dock positions for multiple displays?

Tags: macos, display, dock

Usually, I have my dock on the left of my macbook screen. When I plug in to my big display I would like my left hand monitor to have a dock on the left of the screen and my right hand monitor to have a dock on the right. Otherwise I often have to move my mouse all the way to the opposite side of the opposite monitor just to open up my dock.

Is this possible?

I am running El Capitan if that is relevant.

Comment: Was about to post the same question (running Monterey). I'm hoping there's some way to position the dock on the left hand side on the wider monitor and on the bottom when the display is unplugged